# Antd datepicker (date.clone/date.load is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, antd

I have a react app. There is a checkbox which disables the datepicker. But I can't select any date when I'm using checkbox to disable it. If I remove checkbox and its function there is no error. Currently, I'm getting:

> date.clone is not a function

error.

```js
const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
const today = moment();

const [date, setDate] = useState(today);
const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(false);

  

const onCheckboxHandle = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setwarntill(moment("2090-10-10"));
      setdisabled(true);
    } else {
      setwarntill(today);
      setdisabled(false);
    }
  };
```

```html
<Checkbox onChange={onCheckboxHandle}>Süresiz</Checkbox>
        <Form.Item name={["user", "timetill"]} label="Uyarı Bitiş Tarihi">
          <ConfigProvider locale={locale}>
            <DatePicker
              defaultValue={moment()}
              format={dateFormat}
              onChange={(date,dateString) => setwarntill(dateString)}
              value={warntill}
              disabled={disabled}
            />
          </ConfigProvider>
        </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

parsing the date with the help of moment works for me
`moment(myDate)`

Answer (score 12):

Add valuePropName to <Form.Item>

e.g.

```
<Form.Item valuePropName={'date'}>
    <DatePicker/>
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me. The critical part is that the error is thrown for DatePickers inside of a <Form.Item>. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Feels like magic, but worked for me as well

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer...

Comment: Works like magic!

Answer (score 6):

Put **DatePicker** component outside <Form.Item > <Form.Item /> and check it will work fine.

```
         <DatePicker
            format={"YYYY-MM-DD"}
            onChange={(date, dateString) =>
              this.handleDatepickerChange(date, dateString)
            }
            placeholder="Start Date"
            value={
              this.state.startDate !== ""
                ? moment(this.state.startDate)
                : ""
            }
          />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have realized that when using the  inside <Form.Item > <Form.Item /> it will drop 'date.clone is not a function' error. So you can put the  outside of <Form.Item > <Form.Item /> it should work.

Your code should look like this:

```
const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
const today = moment();

const [date, setDate] = useState(today);
const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(false);



const onCheckboxHandle = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setwarntill(moment("2090-10-10"));
      setdisabled(true);
    } else {
      setwarntill(today);
      setdisabled(false);
    }
  };

<Checkbox onChange={onCheckboxHandle}>Süresiz</Checkbox>
       <ConfigProvider locale={locale}>
            <DatePicker
              defaultValue={moment()}
              format={dateFormat}
              onChange={(date,dateString) => setwarntill(dateString)}
              value={warntill}
              disabled={disabled}
            />
          </ConfigProvider>
```

Comment: I just found that you can use DatePicker inside `<Form.Item>` by removing `initialValue` or `defaultValue`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, it's nothing to do with Form.Item

I have them in Form.Item

I solved this by:

1. initialise the form value when the page load
2. when you initialise, remember, antD default locale is US, therefore, you need to convert your moment or string to moment with MM/DD/YYYY

then this solve my issue

Comment: Better to provide a sample

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this worked for me

```
const today = moment(new Date().getDate(),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the similar issue (date.clone is not a function) when tryed to use saved as a string type data for DatePicker in `initialValues` of `<Form>`. Solved it by passing to initial values not string, but the moment object for DatePicker:

```
  const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  const selectedStartDate = moment('2000-11-11', dateFormat);
  const selectedEndDate = moment('2000-12-11', dateFormat);

  const initValues = {
    startDate: selectedStartDate,
    endDate: selectedEndDate,
  };

  <Form form={form}
        name="basic"
        initialValues={initValues}>
    
    <Form.Item label={'Start'} name={'startDate'}>
      <DatePicker value={selectedStartDate}/>
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item label={'End'} name={'endDate'}>
      <DatePicker value={selectedEndDate}/>
    </Form.Item>

  </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a ternanry condition of isNull then it works....
Something like

```
date_added: _.isNull(date_added) ? null : moment(date_added);
```

Answer (score 0):

the value need a moment.js instance. you should change the `onChange` function to this `onChange={(date,dateString) => setwarntill(date)}`.
and when post to server you should use moment format function to get what server needs format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add getValueProps to <Form.Item>

```
 <Form.Item
  getValueProps={(value) => {
    return { value: dayjs(value) };
  }}
>
  <DatePicker/>
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to explain why this resolves the asker's question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

This Will Fix your issue.

```
Use defaultValue={moment(moment(), dateFormat)}
```