# TypeError: date.clone is not a function After Added the "name" property to Form.Item (ant design)

Tags: datepicker, typeerror, antd

I am currently building an application with DatePicker from Ant Design and I am wrapping with Form.item.

```
      <Form.Item
        name={key}
        label={label}
      >
        <DatePicker
          disabledDate={(current) => disableDaysAfterToday(current)}
          onChange={(current) => handleChangeDate(current)}
        />
      </Form.Item>
```

However, when the "name" property is added to the Form.Item component I end up getting the following error: TypeError: date.clone is not a function. And, if I remove this property or change to some other string, that is, remove "name" from the Form.Item everything works normally. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antd datepicker (date.clone is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527820/antd-datepicker-date-clone-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

The "name" property is used to select the correct attribute in the "initialValues" provided in your `<Form/>` component. If you don't inform it, it doesn't break because the attribute is not being selected, your input must have been empty.

For me, it worked when I treated the attribute in question before passing it to "initialValues".

```
this.object.date = moment(this.object.date);
```